# Limpiar campos marcados por has-error

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Tengo un formulario donde al querer registrar, manda una alerta marcando el contorno de los campos en rojo ademas de mostrar un mensaje, todo esto creado por la clase `has-error`.

Este es el codigo que uso para hacer lo anterior dicho.

```js
$("#itemDes").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#price").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#manufacturer").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#model").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#min").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#max").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#engineer").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#category").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#location").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#supplier").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#unit").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#item").parent().addClass('has-error');
 document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "No puedes dejar campos en blanco, completa la informacion.";
 document.location.href="#errorMessage";
```

Mi problema es que cuando se marcan en rojo y demas, doy cancelar,vuelvo abrir el formulario, estos siguen en rojo, necesito que esto no suceda mas, y que aparezca como la primera vez que se abrio.

Comment: Debería ser suficiente con $('.has-error').removeClass("has-error"); aunque puede que te refieras a hacer un clear del form, en javascript sería: document.getElementById("myForm").reset(); en jquery sería: $('#myForm')[0].reset(); o $('#myForm').trigger("reset");

Comment: Solo necesito que al volver abrir el formulario, ya no esten marcados en rojo ni aparezca el mensaje.

Comment: `$('.has-error').removeClass("has-error");` Esta linea de codigo me ayudo  a quitar el borde rojo cuando se vuelve abrir el formulario, pero el letrero aun sigue apareciendo.

Comment: En el codigo que muestras estas definiendo lo siguiente `document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "block"`. Lo que deberias hacer es, en el evento en el cual se abre el formulario, setear ese elemento con display none, asi: `document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "none"`

Comment: Funciono perfecto @Ale :)